# Asp.net Core 2.0 Restoring Form Values After Postbacks

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

How can I to restore form or query values after postbacks into a view.

In the traditional asp.net mvc I got values using Request.Form but now, in the new version I can't

I would like to restore this values ​​directly on the view without using a model.

I'd like to restore with this way:

```
<label for="FullName">Full Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="Name" value="@Request.Form["FullName"]"  />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Asp.Net Core MVC, you can pass a strongly typed model to the view.  You declare the use of the model at the top of the .cshtml file using

```
 @model MyNamespace.MyModel
```

In such a case if FullName is a property on that model you could do this

But typically developers use a tag helper instead so it would look like this when using the same strongly typed model:

```
 <label asp-for="FullName">Full Name:</label>
 <input asp-for="FullName" type="text" />
```

As a side note, in the controller when you call `return View` you need to pass the model, so it becomes `return View(myModel);` where `myModel` is an instance of the view model you are using for your view, in this case an instance of `MyNamespace.MyModel`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ron,  but I don't want do this way. I'd like do.

I would like to do it directly on the view without using a model

Comment: There is no access to the `Request` object from the view unless you are passing some type of model and pass the request object as a property of that model. But if you are going to to do that, it'd be cleaner to pass specific properties for the form fields as part of the model.

Comment: It may, but in Asp.Net Core there is no static access the `HttpContext` object or it's properties (i.e. Request) from the view or elsewhere.  The framework has been designed around dependency injection and the built in IoC container.  So the Request object is available in the Controller but it's not available in the View unless you pass it to the View via some mechanism.

Comment: In thinking about this more I remembered that you _can_ directly inject services into a view from the IOC container.  Many developers frown on this but the framework supports it.  So if you registered the HttpContextAccessor in the startup.cs you could inject the IHttpContextAccesor into the view, thereby gaining access to the HttpContext object and its Request property.  You can read more about injecting into views here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/dependency-injection This could get you pretty close to the approach you were looking for.